# круговой перебор элементов массива

Tags: java

Как можно реализовать переключение элементов массива (например каналов телевизора) по кругу?
Например при вызове метода nextChannel() с "D" переключиться на "A".

```
public class Tv{
int currentChannel = 1;
int maxChannel = 5;
int step = 1;
List<String> channels = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));


 public String nextChannel() {
        currentChannel += step;
        return String.format("Канал: %s - %s\n", currentChannel, channels.get(currentChannel));
    }
```

Я пытался сделать следующее, но выбрасывается исключение indexOutOfBounds.

```
public String nextChannel() {
        currentChannel += step;
          if(currentChannel > channels.size()){
             currentChannel = 0;
             currentChannel += step;
            }
        return String.format("Канал: %s - %s\n", currentChannel, channels.get(currentChannel));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется итератор в данном случае подходит лучше. К  тому же это не просто итератор, это листитератор, следовательно, можно двигаться не только к следующему каналу, но и к предыдущему:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Tv {
    
    private final List<String> channels;
    private ListIterator<String> iterator;
    
    public Tv(String ... channels) {
        this.channels = Stream.of(channels).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.iterator = this.channels.listIterator();
    }
    
    public String nextChannel() {
        if (iterator.hasNext()) return iterator.next();
        else {
            iterator = channels.listIterator();
            return iterator.next();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tv tv = new Tv("A", "B", "C", "D");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Канал: " + tv.nextChannel());            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если из вашей реализации убрать повторно вкравшееся  увеличение на step, то всё должно работать

```
public String nextChannel() {
        currentChannel += step;
          if(currentChannel > channels.size()){
             currentChannel = 0;
            }
        return String.format("Канал: %s - %s\n", currentChannel, channels.get(currentChannel));
    }
```

Кроме того, можно использовать остаток от деления. Обратите внимание, что возможен и отрицательный шаг благодаря  `+ channels.size()` (не нужен отрицательный  - уберите это)

```
   currentChannel = (currentChannel + step + channels.size()) & channels.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В сравнении нужно использовать == т.к. нумерация массива начинается с 0, и последний адресуемый элемент имеет индекс size-1. В этом причина исключения
2. По той же причине инкремент в if действительно лишний
3. Для удобства пользователя при выводе результата к номеру канала можно прибавлять 1
4. Ели step всегда равен 1, то можно сократить код за счёт оператора инкремента ++.
   Результат может выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   public class Tv {
        private int currentChannel = -1;
        private List<String> channels = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");

        public String nextChannel() {
            if (++currentChannel == channels.size()) {
                currentChannel = 0;
            }
            return String.format("Канал: %s - %s\n", currentChannel + 1, channels.get(currentChannel));
        }
    }
   ```